# Does AsNoTracking works in EF Core compiled queries?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

There is a compiled query:

```
private static readonly Func<LinkorDbContext, IAsyncEnumerable<Item>> _getFreeItemsQuery =
            EF.CompileAsyncQuery((LinkorDbContext dbContext) => dbContext.Items
                .Where(x => x.HttpClientSearch == ItemStatus.Free)
                .AsNoTracking()
            );
```

I obtain results this way:

```
    public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<Item>> Handle()
    {
        var list = new List<Item>();

        await foreach(var item in _getFreeItemsQuery(_context))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I wonder if AsNoTracking() does its job inside compiled query.

Microsoft docs doesn't provide any info aboout EF.CompileAsyncQuery usage, only this obsolete info about Framework version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason for wanting to use `AsNoTracking`, though? I see _a lot_ of people using it in a cargo-cult fashion because they heard "it's faster" but disregarding how it breaks DbContext related Entity Loading detection - hence why I'm curious...

Comment: @dai - I need to run a lot of Queries with high frequence. In my app I have a concurrent collection of items that is being processed by several async tasks, each task has a loop inside that continues to go until the collection is empty (all items processed). And I've come up with an idea to create one db connection for each task (loop). The connection is used to perform some queries and command during each iteration. That is why it is important for me that quering will not result to performance inssues and memory garbaging.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the AsNoTracking() method call inside the EF.CompileAsyncQuery() method will apply the AsNoTracking() behavior to the generated SQL query.
This means that the returned Item objects will not be tracked by the DbContext, and any changes made to them will not be persisted to the database when calling SaveChanges().

AsNoTracking() is a query option that can be used to improve performance when reading data from the database, as it tells Entity Framework not to keep track of the objects returned by the query. This can reduce memory usage and improve performance, especially when dealing with large sets of data.

In your case, the AsNoTracking() method is being called inside the compiled query, so it will be applied to the generated SQL query. This means that the returned Item objects will not be tracked by the DbContext, even though the query is executed asynchronously.

Note that the behavior of AsNoTracking() can be overridden by calling the AsTracking() method on a query. However, since your compiled query only applies AsNoTracking(), this behavior will be preserved regardless of how the query is executed.

Comment: _"so it will be applied to the generated SQL query"_ - please explain how `AsNoTracking` affects SQL query text generation - to my knowledge it shouldn't make any difference at all.

Comment: could you explain how you know this?